# Pylance (VS Code type checking) mistakes the count() infinite iterator as finite

Tags: python, infinite, typechecking, pylance, pyright

I'm relatively new to Pylance (VS Code's static type checker, based on Pyright) and just stumbled upon this type checking error with the `count()` infinite iterator. I have some code I've been playing with, which I reduced to the following basic version which reproduces the problem:

```py
from itertools import count

def foo() -> int:
    for i in count():
        if i == 42:
            return i

print(foo())
```

I'm using this loop over `count()` as essentially a variation of `while True`, to manage an index for me while I'm waiting for a condition to be satisfied. Given it's an infinite loop, the only code path out of this function is via that condition inside the loop which returns an int, but Pylance/Pyright is giving me the following type error:

> Function with declared return type "int" must return value on all code paths
> Type "None" cannot be assigned to type "int" Pylance(reportGeneralTypeIssues)

I saw that I can silence the issue by either of the following:

- Suppressing the warning with `# type: ignore`, which could swallow unrelated issues.
- Making the return type `Optional[int]`, which is strictly wrong.
- Adding a `return -1` (or whatever fake value) at the end, which works, but adds a confusing no-op extra line.
- Or just avoiding the issue and just rewriting this as an explicit infinite loop, which Pylance handles correctly:

```py
def foo() -> int:
    i = 0
    while True:
        if i == 42:
            return i
        i += 1
```

But I'm wondering if there's a cleaner solution here to somehow correctly mark this loop as infinite.

I would also appreciate insight as to the cause - is it just a Pylance/Pyright bug (missing feature), or is there a deeper technical limitation with marking `count()` as an infinite iterator?

Comment: With no way to statically mark iterators as infinite, the closest thing I can think of to a good way to handle this is just sticking `assert False, "Infinite iterator ended!"` after the loop.

Comment: @user2357112, so I suppose that's my question then - is there an inherent limitation saying that iterators cannot be marked as infinite? Is it documented somewhere? Or to ask it another way - is this something that could be addressed at Pyright's level, or would it be something that requires a PEP?

Comment: There is simply no syntax for marking an iterator as infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type system doesn't know whether a generator is infinite or not. There is an issue in `mypy` related to this ([#7374](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/7374)), but it was created in 2019 and it is labeled as low priority.

There is also issue [#5992](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5992), where Guido van Rossum (yes, the creator of Python himself) commented the following:

> Honestly, such code seems really rare, and apart from toy examples like this, it's also hard to analyze for a human. The convention for an unreachable point in the code is `assert False` (which it seems mypy understands).

So I would go for the approach of adding an `assert False` after the loop. Alternatively you could also do something like this (mentioned in #5992):

```python
from itertools import count

def foo() -> int:
    while True:
        for i in count():
            if i == 42:
                return i
```